# Why is my simple java2d Space Invaders game lagging?

Tags: java, 2d, game-engine

I'm currently making a space invaders-esque game for my software engineering course. I've already got everything working that satisfies the requirements, so this isn't a 'solve my homework' kind of question. My problem is that the game will lag (at what seems like random times & intervals) to the point where it becomes too frustrating to play. Some things I think might be causing this - though I'm not positive - are as follows:

Problem with timer event every 10 ms (I doubt this because of the very limited resources required for this game).

Problem with collision detection (checking for collision with every visible enemy every 10 ms seems like it would take up a large chunk of resources)

Problem with repainting? This seems unlikely to me however...

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SIpanel extends JPanel {
    private SIpanel panel;
    private Timer timer;
    private int score, invaderPace, pulseRate, mysteryCount, distanceToEdge;
    private ArrayList<SIthing> cast;
    private ArrayList<SIinvader> invaders, dead;
    private ArrayList<SImissile> missileBase, missileInvader;
    private SIinvader[] bottomRow;
    private SIbase base;
    private Dimension panelDimension;
    private SImystery mysteryShip;
    private boolean gameOver, left, right, mysteryDirection, space, waveDirection;
    private boolean runningTimer;
    private Music sound;


    private void pulse() {
        pace();
        processInputs();
        if (gameOver) gameOver();
        repaint();
    }
    private void pace() {
//      IF invaders still live
        if (!invaders.isEmpty()) {
            invaderPace++;

//          Switch back manager
            if (distanceToEdge <= 10) {
                switchBack();
                pulseRate = (pulseRate >= 16) ? (int) (pulseRate*(0.8)) : pulseRate;
                waveDirection = !waveDirection;
                distanceToEdge = calculateDistanceToEdge();
            }

//              Move invaders left/right
            else if (invaderPace >= pulseRate) {
                invaderPace = 0;
                distanceToEdge = calculateDistanceToEdge();
                moveAI();
                invadersFire();
                if (!dead.isEmpty()) removeDead();
                if (mysteryCount < 1)   tryInitMysteryShip();
            }
//      All invaders are kill, create new wave
        } else if (missileBase.isEmpty() && missileInvader.isEmpty() && !cast.contains(mysteryShip)) {
//          System.out.println("New Wave!");
            newWave();
        }
//      Every pace
        if (!missileBase.isEmpty()) moveMissileBase();
//      Every two paces
        if (invaderPace % 2 == 0)   {
            if (!missileInvader.isEmpty()) moveMissileInvader();
            if (mysteryCount > 0)   moveMysteryShip();
        }
    }
    private void processInputs() {
        if (left)   move(left);
        if (right)  move(!right);
        if (space)  fireMissile(base, true);
    }
    protected void fireMissile(SIship ship, boolean isBase) {
        if(isBase && missileBase.isEmpty()) {
            base.playSound();
            SImissile m = new SImissile(ship.getX()+(ship.getWidth()/2), ship.getY()-(ship.getHeight()/4));
            missileBase.add(m);
            cast.add(m);
        } else if (!isBase && missileInvader.size()<3) {
            base.playSound();
            SImissile m = new SImissile(ship.getX()+(ship.getWidth()/2), ship.getY()+(ship.getHeight()/4));
            missileInvader.add(m);
            cast.add(m);
        }
    }
    private void newWave() {
        pulseRate = 50;
        int defaultY=60, defaultX=120, defaultWidth=30, defaultHeight=24;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<10; j++) {
            if (i<1)    invaders.add(new SItop((j*defaultWidth)+defaultX, (i*defaultHeight)+defaultY, defaultWidth, defaultHeight));
            else if (i<3)   invaders.add(new SImiddle((j*defaultWidth)+defaultX, (i*defaultHeight)+defaultY, defaultWidth, defaultHeight));
            else if (i<5)   invaders.add(new SIbottom((j*defaultWidth)+defaultX, (i*defaultHeight)+defaultY, defaultWidth, defaultHeight));
        }
    }
    for (SIinvader s: invaders) {
        cast.add(s);
    }
    if (!cast.contains(base)) {
        cast.add(base);
    }
    bottomRow = getBottomRow();
}
private void tryInitMysteryShip() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int x=rand.nextInt(1000);
    if (x<=3) {
        mysteryCount = 1;
        if (rand.nextBoolean()) {
            mysteryDirection = true;
        }
        if (mysteryDirection) {
            mysteryShip = new SImystery(0, 60, 36, 18);
        } else {
            mysteryShip = new SImystery(480, 60, 36, 18);
        }
        cast.add(mysteryShip);
    }
}
private void moveMysteryShip() {
    int distance = 0;
    if (mysteryDirection) {
        mysteryShip.moveRight(5);
        distance = getWidth() - mysteryShip.getX();
    } else {
        mysteryShip.moveLeft(5);
        distance = 30+mysteryShip.getX()-mysteryShip.getWidth();
    }
    if (distance <= 5) {
        dead.add(mysteryShip);
        mysteryShip = null;
        mysteryCount = 0;
    }
}
private void removeDead() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ArrayList<SIinvader> temp = (ArrayList<SIinvader>) dead.clone();
    dead.clear();
    for (SIinvader s : temp) {
        invaders.remove(s);
        cast.remove(s);
    }
    bottomRow = getBottomRow();
}
private void invadersFire() {
    int[] p = new int[bottomRow.length];
    for (int i=0; i<p.length; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<p.length; j++) {
            p[j] = j;
        }
        Random rand = new Random();
        int a=rand.nextInt(101);
        if (a>=20) {
            int b=rand.nextInt(p.length);
            fireMissile(bottomRow[b], false);
        }
    }
}
private int calculateDistanceToEdge() {
    int distance = 0;
    SIinvader[] outliers = getOutliers();
    if (waveDirection) {
        distance = getWidth() - outliers[0].getX()-outliers[0].getWidth();
    } else {
        distance = outliers[1].getX();
    }
    return distance;
}
private SIinvader[] getOutliers() {
    SIinvader leftMost = invaders.get(0), rightMost = invaders.get(0);
    for (SIinvader s : invaders) {
        if (s.getX() < leftMost.getX()) {
            leftMost = s;
        }
        if (s.getX() > rightMost.getX()) {
            rightMost = s;
        }
    }
    return new SIinvader[] {    rightMost,  leftMost    };
}
private SIinvader[] getBottomRow() {
    SIinvader[] x = new SIinvader[(invaders.size()>10)?10:invaders.size()];
    for (int i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
        x[i] = invaders.get(i);
        for (SIinvader s:invaders) {
            if (s.getX() == x[i].getX()) {
                if (s.getY() > x[i].getY()) {
                    x[i] = s;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return x;
}
private void move(boolean b) {
    int defaultX = 5;
    if (b) base.moveLeft(defaultX);
    else base.moveRight(defaultX);
}
private void moveAI() {
    for(SIinvader s : invaders) {
        s.changeImage();
        int defaultX = 5;
        if (waveDirection) s.moveRight(defaultX);
        else s.moveLeft(defaultX);
    }
}
private void moveMissileBase() {
    if (invaders.isEmpty()) return;
    int movement = -5, bound = 0;
    SImissile missile = missileBase.get(0);
    missile.moveDown(movement);
    SIinvader lowestInvader = getLowestInvader();
    if (missile.getY() < (lowestInvader.getY() + lowestInvader.getHeight())) {
        for (SIinvader s:bottomRow) {
            if (checkCollision(missile, s)) {
                s.setHit();
                dead.add(s);
                cast.remove(missile);
                missileBase.clear();
                score += s.value;
                return;
            }
        }
        if (mysteryCount > 0) {
            if (checkCollision(missile, mysteryShip)) {
                mysteryShip.setHit();
                dead.add(mysteryShip);
                cast.remove(missile);
                missileBase.clear();
                score += mysteryShip.value;
                return;
            }
        }
        if (missile.getY() < bound) {
            missileBase.remove(missile);
            cast.remove(missile);
        }
    }
}
private SIinvader getLowestInvader() {
    SIinvader lowest = bottomRow[0];
    for (SIinvader invader : bottomRow) {
        if (invader.getY() > lowest.getY()) {
            lowest = invader;
        }
    }
    return lowest;
}
private void moveMissileInvader() {
    int movement = 5, bound = (int) panelDimension.getHeight();
    for (SImissile missile : missileInvader) {
        missile.moveDown(movement);
        if(missile.getY() >= base.getY()) {
            if (checkCollision(missile, base)) {
                base.setHit();
                gameOver = true;;
                missileInvader.remove(missile);
                cast.remove(missile);
                return;
            } else if (missile.getY() >= bound-25) {
                missileInvader.remove(missile);
                cast.remove(missile);
                return;
            }                   
        }
    }
}
private boolean checkCollision(SIthing missile, SIthing ship) {
    Rectangle2D rect1 = new Rectangle2D.Double(
            missile.getX(),
            missile.getY(),
            missile.getWidth(),
            missile.getHeight()
        );
    Rectangle2D rect2 = new Rectangle2D.Double(
            ship.getX(),
            ship.getY(),
            ship.getWidth(),
            ship.getHeight()
        );
    return rect1.intersects(rect2);
}
private void switchBack() {
    int defaultY = 12;
    for (SIinvader s : invaders) {
        if (s.getY() > getHeight()) {
            gameOver = true;
            return;
        }
        s.moveDown(defaultY);
    }
}
private void gameOver() {
    pause(true);
    SI.setGameOverLabelVisibile(true);
}
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    Font font = new Font("Arial", 0, 20);
    setFont(font);
    String score = "Score: "+this.score;
    Rectangle2D rect = font.getStringBounds(score, g2.getFontRenderContext());
    int screenWidth = 0;
    try { screenWidth = (int) panelDimension.getWidth(); }
    catch (NullPointerException e) {}
    g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g2.drawString(score, (int) (screenWidth - (10 + rect.getWidth())), 20);
    for(SIthing a:cast) {
        a.paint(g);
    }
}
    public SIpanel() {
        super();
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        cast = new ArrayList<SIthing>();
        missileBase = new ArrayList<SImissile>();
        score = invaderPace = mysteryCount = pulseRate = 0;
        sound = new Music("AmbientMusic.wav");
        panel = this;

        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT   : left = true; break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT  : right = true; break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE  : space = true; break;
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT   : left = false; break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT  : right = false; break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE  : space = false; break;
                }
            }
        });


        setFocusable(true);

        timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                pulse();
            }
        });
    }
    public void reset() {
        SI.setGameOverLabelVisibile(false);
        score = invaderPace = mysteryCount = 0;
        pulseRate = 50;
        cast = new ArrayList<SIthing>();
        invaders = new ArrayList<SIinvader>();
        dead = new ArrayList<SIinvader>();
        missileBase = new ArrayList<SImissile>();
        missileInvader = new ArrayList<SImissile>();
        base = new SIbase(230, 370, 26, 20);
        waveDirection = true;
        gameOver = false;
        sound.stop();
        sound.loop();
        panelDimension = SI.getFrameDimensions();
        bottomRow = getBottomRow();


        newWave();

        timer.start();
        runningTimer=true;
    }
    public SIpanel getPanel() {
        return this.panel;
    }
    public void pause(boolean paused) {
        if (paused) timer.stop();
        else timer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: `"Why is my **simple** java2d Space Invaders game lagging?"` -- you've posted 375 lines of code, all in one huge class, and this isn't even the entire program -- not a simple program to be sure. Consider isolating your problem by creating a [mcve], a useful tool that helps both you in that it allows you to see your problem naked, and us, in that it allows us to wade through much less code, much more relevant code, and runnable code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks for the reply. I'm going to take a look at what you said and then update my question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that collision detection may be the reason for lagging and you should simply investigate it by trying to increase and decrease count of enemies or missiles drastically to see if that makes a difference.

Consider garbage collector your enemy. In your checkCollision method you are instantiating two (very simple) objects. It may not seem like a lot, but consider that your might be creating them for each collision check, and that at 60fps it adds up until it may reach critical mass when GC says "stop the world" and you see noticeable lag.

If that is the case, possible solution to that would be to not instantiate any objects in a method called so frequently. You may create Rectangle2D once, and then update its position, instead of creating a new one each time, so you will avoid unnecessary memory allocation.

Comment: I have implemented this, but I'm still having the game-breaking lag repeatedly. Could the lag be coming from removing the dead ships from the array list?

Comment: I've set the checkCollision method to always return false by commenting out rect1.intersect(rect2). This removes all lag from the game. Is there any reason for this? It would seem that the checking for intersection itself is causing lag, rather than creating new rectangles over and over.

Comment: Yes, it may be a costly operation, depending on its implementation. To diagnose it, I would recommend using profiler.
One of possible solutions to this problem might be to do so-called throttling (also referred as "deferring"). This technique involves not checking for collisions between each object in each frame, but doing so for only a fraction of objects in a single frame tick, then for another fraction in the next frame tick, so that you cover every object in a set number of frames (i.e. 10 frames, it makes your collision computation less precise for about 1/6 of a second, though)

Comment: Also, I've noticed that you perform collision check between each and every object, meaning O(n^2) quadratic growth.Depending on how many entities you have, you may consider using spatial partitioning algorithm such as quadtree.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. I've actually used a profiler since my last comment and found the source of the lag was the audio clip in the invader class blocking the AWTEventQueue

Comment: I identified the problem and fixed it. It was the AudioClip class creating the lag. I fixed it by using Javafx audioclip instead. Never lags anymore.